# Codeship: How to overide Codeship's automatic git push to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, deployment, codeship

At the end of my build, Codeship does an automatic push to Heroku. I would like to override this push with my own git push. How can I stop these lines from happening:

```
git remote add my-app git@heroku.com:my-app.git
git push heroku_my-app $CI_COMMIT_ID:refs/heads/master
```

What I would like to do is replace Codeship's auto git push with my own git push:

```
git add my-artifact.js
git commit -am "commited"
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:my-app.git
git push -f heroku master
```

Codeship says there's an option to ["configure the Heroku deployment to force push"](https://codeship.com/documentation/faq/push-to-heroku-rejected/#solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

1. Delete the Heroku Deploy Step
2. Create a new Custom Script Deployment Step
3. Add the commands above
4. The go to the Environment Variables section and set HEROKU_API_KEY to your API key that you had used in the original Heroku Deploy Step